ReactNative Navigation show Splash screen again on pressing Back key on Login screen instead of closing the App
I have made an App in ReactNative in that I am using Navigation when I launched the App it show Splash screen and after 3 second it show Login screen but the problem is that when I pressed Backkey it navigate to Splash screen again instead of closing the App.
Here Github project link
Please go through the link and run the project at your end and observed the issue.
EDIT
navigation.replace('Login') solve the problem in ideal way here is a complete code,
const Splash = ({navigation}: {navigation: any}) => {   // const Splash = (props) => {

  setTimeout(() => {
    navigation.replace('Login')
  }, 3000)


Eventually I solved my problem in a gracefully way here is the snip of code.
const Splash = ({navigation}) => {

    setTimeout(()=>{
        navigation.replace('Login') //FIX
    },3000)
}


I have gone through the repo that you added in your question.

From the above picture you have used
props.navigation.navigate("Login")

Instead of using this. you can try 2 different solutions

Use push to navigate to login Screen
Use resetStack and navigate to login Screen.

For 1. You can simply use
Props.navigation.push('Login')

For 2. You have to do it by resetting the stack that you defined as below
navigation.reset({ index: 0,routes: [{ name: 'Login' }]});


resetstack via props.navigation.reset({ index: 0,routes: [{ name: 'Login' }]}); works thanks
